# DNS settings to point domain.com without 'www' to another IP address on ENOM

Tags: domain-name-system, gmail

[image: ENOM DNS Settings]

Hello, A friend of mine has a domain from google (enom) and they are using gmail for their mail accounts. Now we want to host their website on another server. On ENOM I added www record, IP of new server and selected A which is ok for www.domain.com but how can I do settings for only domain.com without 'www' so website will be forwarded but I'll not mess up with emails and the rest.

Thanks in advance Best regards Ergec

Answer (score 1):

Change the A record(s) for "@" which is shorthand for domain.com.